# How to retrieve user roles using @auth0/nextjs-auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to integrate an authentication and user system with Next.js and the `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` lib. I've created two roles in the Auth0 dashboard but I'm struggling to find documentation or a place that gives me some updated information on how do this.

Initially, I was creating an endpoint in the next api called `me`, where I basically made this request:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const userId = req.query.userId as string
  const mgmtApiAccessToken = process.env.MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN

  if (!userId || !mgmtApiAccessToken) return res.status(400).json({
    error: 'Missing required params'
  })

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN_URL}/api/v2/users/${userId}/roles`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${mgmtApiAccessToken}`
      }
    })

    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch user roles')

    const data = await response.json()
    res.status(200).json(data)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty finding the `mgmtApiAccessToken`. Is this really the best approach? Please give me some good tips.